# Simple Regex, match any string with at least one hyphen

Tags: regex

I'm a bit puzzled with a particular regex that is seemingly simple.

The match must be a string with only a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and must have at least one occurence of the '-' character anywhere in the string.

I have `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` but the problem is, it will also match  those without the '-' character.

```
ABC123-ABC //should match

ABC123ABC //shouldn't match.
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This should work:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$
```

Also if you want to have exactly 135 hyphens:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){135}$
```

or if you want to have at least 23 hyphens but not more than 54 hyphens:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*){23,54}$
```

You get the point :)

Comment: Thanks,  do things get really long-winded if you were to require n number of hyphens?

Comment: Just FYI: the first regex provided in this post (`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*$`) matches _exactly_ one hyphen, so if you want _at least_ one hyphen (as stated in your original post), you should wrap it like the others examples and add **+**: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$`

Comment: This will even match the string which has a - only.What if it is always needed to be wrapped between alphanums?Cant we use ([a-zA-Z0-9]+-[a-zA-Z0-9]+) I tried it but It does not matches correctly.Is that the part of string once matched wont be considered for the second time?Sorry I am new in regex and confused.

Answer (score 4):

Peter's solution: (`^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$`) performs well when given a string that matches. However, this expression experiences [Catastrophic Backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) when presented with a non-matching string such as:

`aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa-aa%`

Here are regular expressions which avoid this problem:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*-[-a-zA-Z0-9]*$  # Match one or more -`

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-){5}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ # Match exactly 5 -`

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-){1,5}[a-zA-Z0-9]*$ # Match from 1 to 5 -`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple regex:

```
^(?=.*-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```